# How to make GHCI put new line before expression result

Tags: haskell, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

If I type `1 + 2` into ghci and press enter key, I see this(screenshot below). I would like the result(3 in this case) to be printed on the next line after expression. Is there any way to do this or is it ghci bug?
[image: How my repl loks]

Comment: Normally it should display on the next line automatically!

Comment: This is not normal behavior. What OS and terminal are you using? Does this persist after closing and reopening your terminal window?

Comment: @chi I am using VS Code terminal, Windows 10 and running ghci in wsl2 Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS. Yes, this keeps happening after reopening VS Code.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in VS Code: something there is configuring the terminal wrong, asking it not to create a new line after enter.

Comment: I see you are using GHC 8.8.4, older versions could be more buggy in platforms like Windows. Can you try GHC 8.10.7, or even better, GHC 9.2.4? (Would need to configure ghcup for this)

Comment: @Abastro I installed GHC 9.2.4, it works corectly. But if i install GHCup it in WSL2(so it will be elf executable and use linux syscalls), it fails with gmake error. I would like it to use linux elf executable, but for now I can use windows one.


Error: Process "gmake" with arguments ["DESTDIR=/mnt/c/data/.ghcup/tmp/ghcup-0fb09f0d00c3928e",
                                "install"] failed with exit code 2.
Error: Also check the logs in /mnt/c/data/.ghcup/logs